# No Space left on device when pulling docker image to EC2 Instance(no images or containers exist in the instance)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mingw-w64

I need to clear space but apparently the memory is in the virtual machine not sure how to clear it(i am new to docker and ubuntu).There are no images or containers currently in this EC2 instance,i already deleted them.I am on a window PC.

```
Rae-Djamaal@RaeWallace MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ ssh -i C:\\Users\\Rae-Djamaal\\Desktop\\Stuff_Removed_to_Be_Returned\\putty\\
glm_ubuntu.pem ubuntu@ec2-3-137-150-28.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.3.0-1032-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Tue Sep  8 15:34:13 UTC 2020

  System load:  0.0               Processes:              99
  Usage of /:   99.8% of 7.69GB   Users logged in:        0
  Memory usage: 30%               IP address for eth0:    172.31.44.26
  Swap usage:   0%                IP address for docker0: 172.17.0.1

  => / is using 99.8% of 7.69GB


 * Canonical Livepatch is available for installation.
   - Reduce system reboots and improve kernel security. Activate at:
     https://ubuntu.com/livepatch

18 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


*** System restart required ***
Last login: Tue Sep  8 14:54:08 2020 from 108.28.37.234
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-26:~$
```

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-26:~$ docker pull raedjamw/sf_glm:24.0
24.0: Pulling from raedjamw/sf_glm
6f2f362378c5: Downloading  45.34MB/45.34MB
494c27a8a6b8: Downloading  10.79MB/10.79MB
7596bb83081b: Downloading   4.34MB/4.34MB
372744b62d49: Downloading  50.07MB/50.07MB
615db220d76c: Downloading  215.1MB/215.1MB
1865698adfb0: Downloading  5.747MB/5.747MB
7159b3304cc0: Downloading  20.98MB/20.98MB
ad0713808ef6: Downloading     240B/240B
7ba593904573: Downloading  1.821MB/1.821MB
600301f36ff6: Waiting
b6e81d285b86: Waiting
8d67e206f61c: Downloading   2.64MB/2.64MB
3e2378e7c4a9: Waiting
1764c7ea44b0: Waiting
cfac0d143e72: Waiting
88d5dd814326: Waiting
646c232615bb: Waiting
write /home/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob444753788: no space left on device
```

Comment: As the login and error messages say, the (small, default-sized) disk on your EC2 instance is full.  Your local system isn't really relevant to this.  This also isn't the sort of programming question that's on-topic for Stack Overflow; the [help/on-topic] has more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HTOP](https://htop.dev/) to monitor your local processes and services and use [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) to check what are the files that are consuming your disk space.

Delete some files first to be able to install both htop and ncdu.